# Using scipy.ndimage.filters.percentile_filter for different values of percentile and the same window size

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy

I am calculating the percentile filter over a 2D array using the following function: [scipy.ndimage.filters.percentile_filter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.percentile_filter.html)

This function requires 3 parameters, input, percentile and window size.

I want to evaluate the the input for the various values of percentile but the winsize remains the same.

Could anybody please explain that how could I evaluate my the input with different percentile values, without calculating the percentile over and over.

My array is 3000x2000, the window size is 135, it takes around 3 mins for each call.

Comment: How big is the array? how big is the window? how slow?

Comment: the array is 3000x2000, the window size is 135, it takes around 3 mins for each call